# Java - what kind of thread-safe data strucutre can I use for batch-process as middle-man who accept request and also sent them as batch to end service

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm working on the middle-man and want to group the requests by 10, or whatever the requests are within 100ms after the first request. then I'd like to send them as batch to the end service. It needs to be thread-safe and the request should not be either missed or sent twice.

With key(user id or account id), I was able to do by using both
`Concurrenhashmap<V key, List<Request>> and HashMap<V Key, Object>`

But without using certain key, I cannot think of a good data strucuture for this.

How can I handle above requests?

Comment: Why you need both `Concurrenhashmap<V key, List<Request>> and HashMap<V Key, Object>`?  HashMap<V Key, Object>` is not thread safe

Answer (score 0):

In order to abandon `key`, you need to use concurrent collection.
Here is particular type: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Request>`.
`ConcurrentLinkedQueue` acts like regular Java collection with extra method to support queue operations like `poll()` etc.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Comment: Some more explanation would improve this Answer.